# Can I load a javascript array from an external file?

Tags: javascript

My app uses a lookup table that is embedded in the script. For ease of maintenance I would like to load this table from an external file. What is the best way to accomplish this? I am using the table to specify an image to be loaded on a click event.

```
var categoryTable = {
    "volunteer": "d3_files/images/thunderx64.png",
    "organization": "d3_files/images/cloudyDayx64.png",
    "air":"nothing"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a function in other js file that return this array.
 load that file and call function to get this array.

Answer (score 0):

An external `.js` file can contain any valid Javascript. Putting a variable assignment in it is just fine.

It will have to be a global variable for it to be visible to code in other files.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery getScript() Method:

Quoting from Jquery site:

**Description: Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.**

If your table is JS, then this should help you. However, I think that a better approach would be to rewrite the table code and give it a JSON or XML form. It is is table, then it should be adaptable to some standard form of data representation rather than some custom JS code.

Comment: Samir, I already prepared a json file (my original approach) but did not figure out how to use it,

Comment: @PatriciaW After looking at your question in more detail (admittedly I had just glanced through it), I think that you really do not need any JSON or XML because your JS code is a straight mapping of properties to values already. You simply want this code to be in a separate file. Why not just use the <script> tag separately and have the JS code for just this mapping in that file? Else you can load the JS using getScript method of JQuery as I pointed you to look into. One more thing... If you are not using JQuery, this may be a good excuse to get started. It makes JS programming so easy!

Comment: Thanks, Samir, that works although I don't like the idea of keeping data in a js script. But that is just being a purist.